# Add a JOIN to GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: mysql, join, group-concatenation

I have a table of mostly-static objectives and another to track users' completions of those objectives. They can associate the completion with one or more records entered in another table and/or a text note. I'd like to format all of this together into a single entry for displaying in a table (i.e. one row per objective).

Here's an example of what `Completion` might look like:

```
ID    userID    objectiveID    recordID    text
1     4         8              500         NULL
2     4         8              NULL        "Lorem ipsum..."
3     4         8              750         NULL
```

I've gotten this far:

```
SELECT objectiveID,
   GROUP_CONCAT(recordID SEPARATOR ',') AS records,
   GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR ',') AS text
FROM Completion AS c
GROUP BY objectiveID;
```

Which returns:

```
objectiveID    records    text
8              "500,750"  "Lorem ipsum..."
```

What I'd actually like to display, however, is an attribute of the code being referenced by `recordID`... Suppose that this is the `Record` table:

```
ID    userID    codeID
500   4         1111
750   4         2222
```

And that this is the `Code` table:

```
ID    description
1111  dolor
2222  sit amet
```

My desired output would be:

```
objectiveID    records            text
8              "dolor, sit amet"  "Lorem ipsum..."
```

What's the best approach to get the other values merged in?

Comment: Can you add an example of desired output?

Comment: In the example, `recordID` points to another table `Record`,  each entry of which has a `codeID` column referencing a `Code` table, which has a column of description text. The description is what I'd like to get, for each present `recordID`. I'll update the question as the last bit isn't clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You join `Completion` (columns `userID`,`recordID`) to `Record` (columns `userID`,`ID`)

You join `Record` (column `codeID`) to `Code` (column `ID`)

Here is the proposed query

```
SELECT c.objectiveID,
   GROUP_CONCAT(d.description SEPARATOR ',') AS records,
   GROUP_CONCAT(c.text SEPARATOR ',') AS text
FROM Completion AS c
INNER JOIN Record AS r ON c.userID=r.userID AND c.recordID=r.ID
INNER JOIN Code   AS d ON r.codeID=d.ID
GROUP BY c.objectiveID;
```

Since [GROUP_CONCAT's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) default separator is a comma, you could rewrite as

```
SELECT c.objectiveID,
   GROUP_CONCAT(d.description) AS records,
   GROUP_CONCAT(c.text) AS text
FROM Completion AS c
INNER JOIN Record AS r ON c.userID=r.userID AND c.recordID=r.ID
INNER JOIN Code   AS d ON r.codeID=d.ID
GROUP BY c.objectiveID;
```

Comment: For some reason I'd gotten stuck into thinking that I needed to get a grouping of IDs before the look-up, but that makes perfect sense now. Thanks!